# Meaning of the address printed

Tags: debugging, stack, gdb

This is a simple question I have regarding gdb debugger, when I use the command " i r $rbp" the address that is printed is the actual address of rbp or just an address the points to rbp's address? thank you

Answer (score 3):

> is the actual adress of rbp or just an adress the points to rbp's adress

You are confused: registers do not have addresses, only names.

When you do `info register $rbp`, you get the *value* stored in the register. That value may be interpreted as an integer, or an address, or a float. It's just bits.

Comment: so are you saying that the value rbp stores is a pointer to the stack's base?

Comment: @pedrosantos In debug builds, $rbp is usually used as a frame pointer (i.e. the value $rbp when interpreted as a pointer, points to the current frame base). In optimized builds the value of $rbp could be anything.